# which mode we should use when running spark on yarn?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I know there are two modes while running spark applications on yarn cluster.

In **yarn-cluster** mode, the driver runs in the Application Master (inside a YARN cluster). In **yarn-client** mode, it runs in the client node where the job is submitted

I wanted to know what are the advantages of using one mode over the other ? Which mode we should use under what circumstances.

Comment: I guess I can't provide better answer than [this](https://www.quora.com/When-should-apache-spark-be-run-in-yarn-cluster-mode-vs-yarn-client-mode-A-use-case-example-for-both-approaches-would-be-more-helpful).
Only thing I can add, it's more convenient to use yarn-cluster mode when you run your job with Oozie, since you can just put your app jar into HDFS and give jar path as parameter to Oozie Spark Action. On the other side, it's easier to check logs in console when you run your app in yarn-client mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two deploy modes that can be used to launch Spark applications on YARN.

**Yarn-cluster:** the Spark driver runs within the Hadoop cluster as a YARN Application Master and spins up Spark executors within YARN containers. This allows Spark applications to run within the Hadoop cluster and be completely decoupled from the workbench, which is used only for job submission. An example:

```
[terminal~]:cd $SPARK_HOME
[terminal~]:./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn 
–deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 3 --driver-memory 1g --executor-memory 
2g --executor-cores 1 --queue thequeue $SPARK_HOME/examples/target/spark-examples_*-1.2.1.jar
```

Note that in the example above, the –queue option is used to specify the Hadoop queue to which the application is submitted.

**Yarn-client:** The Spark driver runs on the workbench itself with the Application Master operating in a reduced role. It only requests resources from YARN to ensure the Spark workers reside in the Hadoop cluster within YARN containers. This provides an interactive environment with distributed operations. Here’s an example of invoking Spark in this mode while ensuring it picks up the Hadoop LZO codec:

```
[terminal~]:cd $SPARK_HOME
[terminal~]:bin/spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --queue research 
--driver-memory 512M --driver-class-path /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.4.18-201409171947.jar
```

So when you want interactive environment for your job, you should use **client mode**. The yarn-client mode accepts commands from the spark-shell.

When you want to decouple your job from Spark workbench, use Yarn cluster mode.

Comment: Thanks Nishu . This is very well explained in detail . So based on the above explaination , would it be fair to say  in production like environments especially when are scheduling cron jobs to run spark-apps we should be using yarn-cluster mode ( As we dont need interactive environment) ? Also in very rare situations like where our edge node is being used my users to submit the jobs , we should prefer yarn-cluster mode to avoid  too much load on client node. Generally in dev-environments , we can use yarn-client mode where we may need to supply additional commands(kill)

Comment: Yes, you can say that. For more details, you can refer the [Running spark App on Yarn](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_on_yarn.html)